# how to import Toggle in Material-ui@next

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have upgraded material ui version to v1.0.0-beta.26. With this update I am facing module not found issue when I try to import Toggle as like below.

```
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`Switch`](https://material-ui-next.com/api/switch/):

> On/off switches toggle the state of a single settings option. The
>   option that the switch controls, as well as the state it’s in, should
>   be made clear from the corresponding inline label.

```
import Switch from 'material-ui/Switch';
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for Toggle in latest documentation. Its resolved with Switch.